# How to stop the Symbol markers (arrows) from moving after being rotated?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When changing the rotation parameters from 45 degrees to 315 degrees, you will notice that the marker icon will not rotate from its center and it will move. I want to be able to rotate from its center and stay in its fixed coordinates.

Thank you so much in advance.

I already tried using the fixedRotation: true parameter and I dont' understand the anchor parameter.

```
      var windlocation = {lat: 18.331780, lng: -64.95246};
      var currentlocation = {lat: 18.331780, lng: -64.950632};

      var windmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: windlocation,
        map: map,
        icon:  {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        rotation: 45,
        fixedRotation:true,
        offset: '0%',
        scale: 7,
        strokeColor: 'green',
        strokeWeight: 3

      }

      });

      var currentmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentlocation,
        map: map,
        icon:  {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,            
        rotation: 45,
        fixedRotation:true,
        offset: '0%',
        scale: 7,
        strokeColor: 'blue',
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: 'blue'

        }
```

no error message, just need to keep the markers in a fixed place after being rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor by default is at the "point" of the arrow.  If you want it to rotate around the center of the arrow, set the anchor to `anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 2.5)`

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g918z3bs/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16
  });
  var windlocation = {
    lat: 18.331780,
    lng: -64.95246
  };
  var currentlocation = {
    lat: 18.331780,
    lng: -64.950632
  };

  var windmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: windlocation,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      rotation: 45,
      fixedRotation: true,
      offset: '0%',
      scale: 7,
      strokeColor: 'green',
      strokeWeight: 3
    }
  });
  var m1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: windlocation,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
    }
  });

  var currentmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currentlocation,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      rotation: 0,
      fixedRotation: true,
      offset: '0%',
      scale: 7,
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: 'blue',
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 2.5)
    }
  });
  var m2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currentlocation,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
    }
  });
  map.setCenter(windmarker.getPosition());
  setInterval(function() {
    var icon = currentmarker.getIcon();
    icon.rotation += 5;
    icon.rotation %= 360;
    currentmarker.setIcon(icon);
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```